# Temp record Insertion technique

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am using sql server 2008. I have to insert records in temporary table using multiple select statements like below.

```
Insert into #temp
Select a From TableA

Insert into #temp
Select a From TableB

Insert into #temp
Select a From TableC

Insert into #temp
Select a From TableD
```

OR

```
Insert Into #temp
Select A From
(
    Select A from TableA
    Union
    Select B From TableB
    Union
    Select B From TableC
)K
```

Please advice which approach should be best or any other and Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two techniques you present are not interchangeable. The `UNION` operation will remove duplicate values while the individual `INSERT` operations will not. To get identical results, you'd need to use `UNION ALL`.